# No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer)

Tags: groovy, closures

I am writing a groovy code, when I hit the error reading like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), grep(), getClass(), wait(long)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at myPackage.myClass.myMethod_closure3_closure5.doCall(line:xyz)
    :
    :
```

So as you can see on the last line, my method have two nested closures. The line number xyz is doing something like this:

```
(rvar1,rvar2) = methodThatReturnsMultipleValues(param1,param2)
```

I debugged the code and found that `methodThatReturnsMultipleValues()` returns `[false,false]`, something like this:

```
methodThatReturnsMultipleValues(def param1,def param2)
{
    //...
    return [false,false]
}
```

However when I step out of the method while debugging the line number xyz gives above exception. According to groovy, this should assign both `rvar1` and `rvar2` to `false`. I tried to replicate the exception on smaller code like this:

```
class TempClass
{
    static main(def args)
    {
         boolean bvar1 = false
         boolean bvar2 = false
         (bvar1, bvar2) = returnMultipleValues()
         println bvar1
         println bvar2
    }

    static private returnMultipleValues()
    {
        boolean a = false
        boolean b = false
        return [a, b]
    }
}
```

However, unfortunately above code works perfect and correctly prints `false` twice. So am not able to replicate the issue on small code. Surprisingly, when I change the line xyz to:

```
def a = methodThatReturnsMultipleValues(param1,param2)
```

`a` gets assigned with `true` and continues in desired manner, given that I am testing for scenarios in which `rvar1` and `rvar2` will not be used. Its only when I change back the line xyz to

```
(rvar1,rvar2) = methodThatReturnsMultipleValues(param1,param2)
```

the error pops up again, failing scenarios where `rvar1` and `rvar2` will be used.

I am just lost with direction where should I be looking for. Especially that `java.lang.Boolean.getAt()` is not making me much sense.

PS: I know only explaining the behavior of code as I observe might not be completely helpful to resolve my query, and I should be giving the full code so that others can also observe more stuff, but honestly my code is not easy to make standalone, I mean directly callable from `main()`. So let me know if I should take extra effort to really make it callable from `main()` and really replicate the issue on as small code as possible. But before that I will really appreciate any blind guesses towards resolving this.

Comment: You have an error in `methodThatReturnsMultipleValues` in that it sometimes will just return a single boolean value.

Comment: ok I want to honestly tell that while debugging, inside `methodThatReturnsMultipleValues`, the execution pointer does come on `return [var1,var2]` and both `var1`,`var2` contains `false`. But now as you pointed out, I feel its because of incorrect debugging shown by Groovy Grails Tools Suit. I know its execution pointer sometimes jumps on lines which does not actually get executed actually. The actual return value must be governed by the last statements inside closure above `return [var1,var2]`. Between if that is the case, is there any other better debugging environment than GGTS?

Comment: IntelliJ?  Or just add `println` statements to show what is happening at different branch points in your code

Comment: To expand on @tim_yates's comment.  That error would be thrown if your closure returned a boolean value like `false` instead of a list of boolean values `[false]` or `[false, false]`

Comment: ok I got that and I will debug `methodThatReturnsMultipleValues`. But just curious how returning just `boolean` instead of list translates to `No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]`? In fact I dont get what this exception explanation is trying to tell. What is its meaning and how it relates to the problem of returning just boolean value but not the list.

Comment: pk sad thing happenned. I asked one of colleague to have a look at the code and after some time its not that `methodThatReturnsMultipleValues` is returning boolean value. It is trying to return `LinkedHashMap` only, but I accidentally explicitly defined the return type of it to be `boolean`, so it is converting non-null `LinkedHashMap` to `true`...

Comment: ...Now that is not my general habit.  In groovy, I almost always define methods without defining return type, so I was sort of blind not to check the return type. But it hearts when you realize ur stupidity and loose your precious time. Honestly, I feel groovy should have given me AT LEAST WARNING like "Defined to return boolean, but returning LinkedHashMap" inspite of giving that 'No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.getAt()...' exception...

Comment: ...In fact everyone thought that the method must have returned `boolean`, no one thought I myself have defined method to return `boolean`. They were blind by my sample code, I was blind by my habit. :(